# remove time(s) from string with javascript

Tags: javascript

How can i remove the time(s) from the string on page load with javascript

*this string is dynamically getting pulled in so the times will not be the same everytime

string/html:

```
 <div id="dateTime">
( ex1 )06/05/2020 09:32:54) | ( ex2 )06/05/2020 09:34:40) 1) | ( ex3 )06/08/2020 09:05:22) | ( ex4 )06/08/2020 13:10:39)  | (ex5 )06/08/2020 16:44:25) |
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
window.onload = function () {
var Datetime= document.getElementById('dateTime'); 
//remove time from string

???

//print new string
document.getElementById("dateTime").innerHTML = ;
}
```

Comment: what does the string look like?

Comment: ( ex1 )06/05/2020 09:32:54) | ( ex2 )06/05/2020 09:34:40) 1) | ( ex3 )06/08/2020 09:05:22) | ( ex4 )06/08/2020 13:10:39)  | (ex5 )06/08/2020 16:44:25) |

Comment: Is that literally your string or are those multiple examples?

Comment: that is the string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could run a [string.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and use a [RegEx](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) to simply strip out all the times:

```js
const data = '( ex1 )06/05/2020 09:32:54) | ( ex2 )06/05/2020 09:34:40) 1) | ( ex3 )06/08/2020 09:05:22) | ( ex4 )06/08/2020 13:10:39)  | (ex5 )06/08/2020 16:44:25) |';

// match the time pattern
const re = /(\s\d{1,2}\:\d{1,2}\:\d{1,2})/gm;

// replace the matches with empty string
console.info(data.replace(re, ''));
```